# How to fix error css width x height when run as mobile

Tags: css

I have a image:

```
<img class="" width="78px" height="78px" border="0" alt="" src="test.png" smartload="7" style="opacity: 1;">
```

And css:

```
img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

When run as PC (firefox)

[image: PC]

When run as mobile is height error:

[image: Mobile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want things to scale to ratio, don't set a width and height... set just one of them.  The browser will automatically scale the other dimension for you, based on the height/width ratio.

I'd drop your width/height in the tag, and set just width in your CSS.

```
width: 78px;
max-width: 100%;
```

You generally don't need `max-width: 100%`.